# Change a dataframe of floats and objects into a binary dataframe whilst retaining string values of column and row headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, integer

This is my dataset:

| Name | Test1 | Test3 | Test2 | Quiz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boo | 0.9 | 0 | 0 | 1.0 |
| Buzz | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0 | 0 |
| Bree | 0 | 0 | 1.0 | 0 |

How I want my result dataset:

| Name | Test1 | Test3 | Test2 | Quiz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boo | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Buzz | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Bree | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I tried the df.astype to int64 - but this changed all values below 1 to 0. I also tried:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

but this caused my first column to become NaN values. I also tried:

```
df.where(df <= 0.4, 1, inplace=True)
```

but I got an error saying this isn't possible between str and float. I had set_index() in the Name column, so ideally this error shouldn't come. I can't seem to figure this out, need major help :((

Comment: values  only 1 or 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Name').astype('float').gt(0.4).astype('int').reset_index()
```

output:

```
    Name    Test1   Test3   Test2   Quiz
0   Boo     1       0       0       1
1   Buzz    1       1       0       0
2   Bree    0       0       1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends of treshold - if need `1` if values greater like `0.4` compare for boolean mask and convert to integers for `True, False` to `1,0` mapping:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.set_index('Name')

df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').gt(0.4).astype(int)
print (df1)
      Test1  Test3  Test2  Quiz
Name                           
Boo       1      0      0     1
Buzz      1      1      0     0
Bree      0      0      1     0
```

Comment: But this caused all the values in the 'Name' column to change to 0. I did reset index, but it seems to switch to the first column every time I write a new command.